# Ruby streaming over collection as in Smalltalk

Tags: ruby, stream

Does Ruby have the ability to stream over collections (of anything), as in Smalltalk?

Comment: Can you show what behavior you want to achieve? I am not sure what you mean with "stream over collections". [Here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) is an overview how collections can be accessed in ruby.

Comment: I _think_ you might mean an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html), although it’s not clear from your question what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to speak about Arrays Iterations, the most similar concept in Ruby

[object1, object2, object3].each do |obj|
    # do with your iterate obj
  end

break/jump are possible with 'break,next' keywords
objects could be heterogeneous or not (string lines from a IO::readlines for example)

if you want to analyse a large text file as a stream, split it as an Array, and you could use 
matching (regexp) methods, searching methods, modifying methods on it before to join a copy

Comment: I am looking for a Stream class. A stream contains a collection as well as a pointer into that collection.  Stream encapsulates positionable stepping through a collection.

Comment: Enumerator looks promising, but I want to start the enumeration from an offset.  For example:

Comment: Enumerator looks promising, but I want to start the enumeration from an offset, starting after the first n elements.  There doesn't seem to be a way to set the position of the internal iterator (as in a classic PositionableStream).

Comment: @user2840838 [drop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) might be what you want to look at.